# Use Class For Eonasdan Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, eonasdan-datetimepicker

How to use class fo Eonasdan datetimepicker instead of using ID to enable the picker. And try to enable all having the same class use Eonasdan datetimepicker.

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/aice09/cdaw62jz/

```js
 $(function() {
   $('#enablepicker').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```html
<!--JQUERY-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap 3.3.7-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Font-awesome 4.7.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Date Timepicker-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    
    <div class="row">
  <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group date enablepicker' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control"  placeholder="Datetimepicker 1"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group date enablepicker' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Datetimepicker 2" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you want to use classes instead of id, you have to use class selector (`$('.enablepicker')`) instead of id (`$('#enablepicker')v`) selector. Simply change `#` to `.`

Comment: @VincenzoC , I tried that also but only one will be affected. Only one having the class.

Comment: Using `$('.enablepicker')` instead of `$('#enablepicker')` in the linked fiddle works for both components.

Comment: Yes, it works in JSFiddle but still didn't work in dynamic row datatable.@VincenzoC

Comment: You have to call `datetimepicker()` when the dinamically added rows are already attached to the DOM. I think you have to edit your question showing the code for add rows dinamically, your question, in its current form, is  about a _simple typographical error_.